# Is there a way to hide gcd?

Tags: haskell, overriding, haskell-prelude

I am rewriting the `gcd` function for an assignment, but when I'm trying to hide `gcd`, like so:

```
import Prelude hiding ((gcd))
```

I get the error

> Parse error on input'gcd'.

I'm certain I've completed the redefinition of `gcd`, but I can't stop the error

> Ambiguous occurrence, it could refer to 'Prelude.gcd'

unless I manage to hide `gcd`.

Here is my full code (apologies can't find upload file):

```hs
import Prelude hiding ((||)) 
import Prelude hiding ((gcd))

gcd :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd x y
    | x == y    = x
    | x < y     = gcd x (y-x)
    | otherwise = gcd (x-y) y
```

And here is my error after changing to `import Prelude hiding (gcd)`:

[image: Error]

Comment: `import Prelude hiding (gcd)` - `gcd` is a prefix function by default, not infix, so it doesn't need parentheses to refer to it

Comment: Amazing, thank you, but I still get the ambiguous error if I do that.

Comment: You do? Please post your full `.hs` file (or terminal transcript if you did this in GHCi).

Comment: Try using fewer parentheses.  Like @RobinZigmond said, add `import Prelude hiding (gcd)`, not `((gcd))`.

Comment: Here is my code for the gcd function
```haskell
gcd :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd x y
    | x == y    = x
    | n < m     = gcd x (y-x)
    | otherwise = gcd (x-y) y
```

Comment: here is my error:

Week3.hs:96:19: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘gcd’
    It could refer to either ‘Prelude.gcd’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at Week3.hs:4:1-28
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Real’)
                          or ‘Main.gcd’, defined at Week3.hs:93:1
   |
96 |     | otherwise = gcd (x-y) y
   |                   ^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.

Comment: What are `m` and `n`? And please edit the entirety of `Week3.hs` into the question.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thank you, artifact from a previous version, adding file now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hide multiple things from a module, you need to import it once and specify everything to hide. Importing it twice will result in each line's exclusions nullifying the other. So do this instead:

```
import Prelude hiding ((||), gcd)
```

(And as previously mentioned in the comments, `gcd` isn't an operator, so it shouldn't have parentheses around it like `||` does.)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, this has resolved the issue.